# Laravel 5.3 to 5.4 (mPdf - niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf ) upgrade issue

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, mpdf, laravel-5.4

Laravel 5.3 to 5.4  (mPdf - niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf) upgrade issue

```
ErrorException in PdfServiceProvider.php line 28:
Missing argument 2 for niklasravnsborg\LaravelPdf\PdfServiceProvider::niklasravnsborg\LaravelPdf{closure}(), called in C:\xamp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 678 and defined
```

Comment: Your mistake was upgrading before making sure your  3rd party dependencies are fully compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Change file vender\niklasravnsborg\LaravelPdf\PdfServiceProvider line 28 code

```
$this->app->bind('mpdf.wrapper', function($app, $cfg) {
    return new PdfWrapper();
});
```

to

```
$this->app->bind('mpdf.wrapper', function($app) {
    return new PdfWrapper();
});
```